# Identifying geodataframe points within multiple JSON polygons

Tags: python, geospatial, geojson, point, geopandas

I have a geodataframe with a column of geometry points (Lat/Long), as well as individual "Lat" and "Long" columns. (I don't mind which one the solution uses)

I also have a geojson with NUTS1 regions of the uk. The keyword for the region names is "nuts118nm".

How can I iterate through my geodataframe, creating a new column that has the name of whatever region each point falls within?

I've looked into shapely but to no luck. Quite new to geospatial data. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you should provide code from any attempts you made

Comment: You are looking for overlay http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html

Comment: @REESJ if you want more concrete answers, it is best to provide some example code with sample data that shows the problem.